# LaTeX File and Folder Symbols

Tags: symbols

Are there file and folder/directory symbols in **LaTeX**?

Something like:

[image: file and folder symbols]

Comment: `\includegraphics` is your friend: it can be used anywhere.

Comment: @egreg, I don't want to include the above shown graphics, it's just a quick example. I am looking for a symbol like in Heiko Oberdiek's answer.

Comment: Make a PNG or PDF from it and use `\includegraphics`, if you can't use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @egreg can `\includegraphics` used inside `tikzpicture`?

Comment: @alper Of course it can.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can include any graphic file with pdflatex. Just use XeLaTeX to prepare them.

For instance, save the following file as `FolderOpen.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{24}{0}\selectfont
\faFolderOpen
\end{document}
```

Compile it with XeLaTeX and use the PDF file like shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\FolderOpen}[1][.8\ht\strutbox]{%
  \includegraphics[height=#1]{FolderOpen}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\FolderOpen] This is an open folder
\item This isn't
\end{itemize}

Also a big open folder: \FolderOpen[1cm].
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `fontawesome` package now doesn't need the `fontspec` and works with PdfTeX / PdfLaTeX

Comment: @JakubNarębski Yes, that was added.

Answer (score 21):

Font Awesome contains symbols for file and folder. However it needs XeTeX or LuaTeX, example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
  File: \faFile\ \faFileAlt\par
  Folder: \faFolderOpen\ \faFolderClose\ \faFolderOpenAlt\ \faFolderCloseAlt
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Without LuaTeX/XeTeX

The symbol can be put in a stand-alone file. Then LuaTeX/XeTeX generates a PDF file that is then included as graphics, e.g.:

```
% FileAlt.tex
% lualatex/xelatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}%
\faFileAlt
\end{document}
```

Then the file `FileAlt.pdf` is generated:

```
lualatex FileAlt
```

and the result `FileAlt.pdf` can be included with pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics{FileAlt}
\end{document}
```

Also an EPS file can be generated, e.g.:

```
pdftoeps -eps FileAlt.pdf
```

However, the bounding box is not too precise, it can be improved. Also
I got some problems, if the included file is converted to PDF again,
therefore I added a third step with purifyeps that converts the EPS
to a simpler PostScript without font dependency:

```
pdftops -eps FileAlt.pdf temp1.eps
epstool --copy --bbox --output temp2.eps temp1.eps
purifyeps temp2.eps FileAlt.eps
```

Then it can be included with latex/dvips:

```
\includegraphics[hiresbb]{FileAlt}
```

Comment: Very nice! However I can't use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @sergej: The `fontawesome` package now doesn't need the `fontspec` and works with PdfTeX / PdfLaTeX. Note that it is `\faFileO`, not `\faFileAlt`.

Answer (score 9):

With `tikz`. Find a `.svg` file, open it in inkscape, and export as `tikz` code using `inkscape2tikz`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{cc4a000}{RGB}{196,160,0}
\definecolor{ceeeeec}{RGB}{238,238,236}
\definecolor{c204a87}{RGB}{32,74,135}
\definecolor{cedd400}{RGB}{237,212,0}


\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.8pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{scope}[shift={(-20.42857,-28.63543)}]
    \path[draw=black,fill=cc4a000,line join=round,line cap=round,miter
      limit=4.00,dash phase=15.792pt,line width=1.600pt,rounded corners=0.0000cm]
      (21.4286,186.6479) rectangle (708.5715,643.7908);
    \begin{scope}[cm={{0.58178,-0.81335,0.81335,0.58178,(165.90533,-14.59901)}}]
      \path[cm={{-0.00202,1.0,-1.0,-0.00202,(0.0,0.0)}},draw=black,fill=ceeeeec,line
        join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=4.00,dash phase=15.792pt,line
        width=1.600pt,rounded corners=0.0000cm] (99.7727,-17.2073) rectangle
        (641.2012,342.8532);
      \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,0.52631,(-1.66834,57.53025)}}]
        \path[draw=c204a87,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=1.103pt]
          (-317.9725,156.1510) -- (-5.8354,156.1510);
        \path[draw=c204a87,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=1.103pt]
          (-317.9725,121.9502) -- (-5.8354,121.9502);
        \path[draw=c204a87,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=1.103pt]
          (-317.9725,190.3519) -- (-5.8354,190.3519);
        \path[draw=c204a87,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=1.103pt]
          (-317.9725,224.5528) -- (-5.8354,224.5528);
        \path[draw=c204a87,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=1.103pt]
          (-317.9725,258.7537) -- (-5.8354,258.7537);
        \path[draw=c204a87,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=1.103pt]
          (-317.9725,327.1554) -- (-5.8354,327.1554);
        \path[draw=c204a87,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=1.103pt]
          (-317.9725,361.3563) -- (-5.8354,361.3563);
        \path[draw=c204a87,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=1.103pt]
          (-317.9725,395.5572) -- (-5.8354,395.5572);
        \path[draw=c204a87,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=1.103pt]
          (-317.9725,429.7581) -- (-5.8354,429.7581);
        \path[draw=c204a87,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=1.103pt]
          (-317.9725,463.9590) -- (-5.8354,463.9590);
        \path[draw=c204a87,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=1.103pt]
          (-317.9725,498.1598) -- (-5.8354,498.1598);
        \path[draw=c204a87,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=1.103pt]
          (-317.9725,532.3607) -- (-5.8354,532.3607);
        \path[draw=c204a87,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=1.103pt]
          (-317.9725,566.5616) -- (-5.8354,566.5616);
        \path[draw=c204a87,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=1.103pt]
          (-317.9725,600.7625) -- (-5.8354,600.7625);
        \path[draw=c204a87,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=1.103pt]
          (-317.9725,292.9545) -- (-5.8354,292.9545);
      \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
    \path[draw=black,fill=cedd400,line join=round,line cap=round,miter
      limit=4.00,dash phase=15.792pt,line width=1.600pt] (178.1531,232.3622) --
      (795.0523,232.3622) .. controls (814.5098,232.3622) and (825.9769,246.5090) ..
      (820.7633,264.0816) -- (717.0939,613.5000) .. controls (711.8803,631.0725) and
      (692.0187,645.2193) .. (672.5613,645.2193) -- (55.6620,645.2193) .. controls
      (36.2045,645.2193) and (24.7374,631.0725) .. (29.9510,613.5000) --
      (133.6204,264.0816) .. controls (138.8340,246.5090) and (158.6956,232.3622) ..
      (178.1530,232.3622) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Do the same for file icon or simply draw it:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,1.2) -- (0.7,1.2) -- (0.7,0.8) -- (1,0.8) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
  \draw (0.7,1.2) -- (1,0.8);
  \foreach \y in {0.2,0.4,0.6}{
     \draw (0.2,\y) -- (0.8,\y);
     \draw (0.2,0.8) -- (0.6,0.8);
     \draw (0.2,1) -- (0.6,1);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you want to have a **node shape** (in PGF/TikZ) that looks like a *file* or a *folder* symbol, you can use the following code (which can also be found, with two more shapes, in [this example Overleaf project](https://www.overleaf.com/3844747wrzspt)).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\makeatletter
% based on
% https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jubobs/gitdags/master/gitdags.sty
% custom shape, adapted from 102.5.3 in the TikZ 3.0 manual
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  dogear size/.initial=5pt,
}
\pgfdeclareshape{dogeared}{ % or 'document', or 'file'
  % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}

  \savedmacro\dogearsize{%
    \edef\dogearsize{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dogear size}}%
  }

  \backgroundpath{% this is new
    % store lower left in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    % compute corner of ‘‘flipped page’’ (‘‘dog ear’’)
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@xb \advance\pgf@xc by-\dogearsize
    \pgf@yc=\pgf@yb \advance\pgf@yc by-\dogearsize
    % construct main path
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathclose
  }
  \foregroundpath{% this is new
    % store lower left in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    % compute corner of ‘‘flipped page’’ (‘‘dog ear’’)
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@xb \advance\pgf@xc by-\dogearsize
    \pgf@yc=\pgf@yb \advance\pgf@yc by-\dogearsize
    % construct main path
    %%
    % add little corner
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
    \pgfpathclose
  }
}

%% based on code in
%% https://github.com/GuITeX/guidatikzmark/blob/master/pacchetti_comandi/documento.tex
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  tab height/.initial=3pt,
  tab width/.initial=10pt,
  tab slope/.initial=1.5pt,
  cover xoff/.initial=5pt,
  cover yoff/.initial=2pt,
}
%% Note: use '\setlength{\pgf@xd}{\pgf@xb}' rather than '\pgf@xd=\pgf@xb'
%% ??? for some reason \pgf@ytt etc. didn't work, but \pgf@yd does
\newlength\pgf@yd
\newlength\pgf@xe
\newlength\pgf@xf
\newlength\pgf@xg
\newlength\pgf@yg
\newlength\pgf@xh
%% this didn't work
\newlength\pgf@xo  %% note: \pgf@xx is pre-defined by pgf to mean something

%% from 95.2 Communicating with the Basic Layer via Macros
% \newdimen\pgf@xta \newdimen\pgf@xtb \newdimen\pgf@ytt
% \newdimen\pgf@xoa \newdimen\pgf@xob \newdimen\pgf@yoo
\pgfdeclareshape{folder open}{ % or 'directory'
  %% this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}

  \savedmacro\tabheight{%
    \edef\tabheight{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/tab height}}%
  }
  \savedmacro\tabwidth{%
    \edef\tabwidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/tab width}}%
  }
  \savedmacro\tabslope{%
    \edef\tabslope{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/tab slope}}%
  }
  \savedmacro\coverxoff{%
    \edef\coverxoff{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cover xoff}}%
  }
  \savedmacro\coveryoff{%
    \edef\coveryoff{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cover yoff}}%
  }
  %% this didn't work; probably needs \pgf@process somewhere...
  % \setlength{\pgf@xo}{\coverxoff}
  % \setlength{\pgf@xo}{0.5\pgf@xo}

  %% this didn't work either
  % \setlength{\pgf@xo}{2pt}
  % \advance\pgf@xo by \coverxoff\relax

  %% this didn't work either
  % \pgf@xx=0pt
  % \advance\pgf@xx by \coverxoff\relax
  % \pgf@xx=0.5\pgf@xx

  %% fallback, so this at least compile
  %% but moves text, because \pgf@xx is sed for node contents positioning
  % \pgf@xx=2pt % this should be 0.5 of \coverxoff

  % \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \anchor{west}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@ya=.5\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\southwest}%
    \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y%
    \advance\pgf@y by  \pgf@ya%
    \advance\pgf@x by -2pt%
  }
  % \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \anchor{east}{%
    \pgf@process{\southwest}%
    \pgf@ya=.5\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y%
    \advance\pgf@y by  \pgf@ya%
    \advance\pgf@x by  2pt%
  }
  \backgroundpath{% this is new
    %% store lower left in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    %% correction due to open front cover
    \advance\pgf@xa by -2pt
    \advance\pgf@xb by -2pt
    %% 
    %% compute edges of the "divider tab" in the back cover
    %% 
    \setlength{\pgf@yd}{\pgf@yb}
    \advance\pgf@yd by \tabheight
    \setlength{\pgf@xe}{\pgf@xa}
    \advance\pgf@xe by \tabwidth % or make it dependent on box width
    \setlength{\pgf@xf}{\pgf@xe}
    \advance\pgf@xf by \tabslope % or make it dependent on divider height
    %% 
    %% compute edges of second cover of a folder ("open" cover)
    %% 
    \setlength{\pgf@xg}{\pgf@xa}
    \advance\pgf@xg by \coverxoff % perhaps as an angle of open
    \setlength{\pgf@xh}{\pgf@xb}
    \advance\pgf@xh by \coverxoff 
    \setlength{\pgf@yg}{\pgf@yb}
    \advance\pgf@yg by-\coveryoff % perhaps as an angle of open
    %% 
    %% construct main path
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yd}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xe}{\pgf@yd}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xf}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yg}} % break for open cover
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    % \pfgpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}} % ??? causes error ???
    \pgfpathclose
    %% construct secondary path
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xg}{\pgf@yg}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xh}{\pgf@yg}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathclose
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,draw]

    \node [dogeared,fill=red!20,draw=red!20!black]
          at (0, 0.0) { dogeareds };
    \node [folder open,fill=orange!20,draw=orange!20!black]
          at (0,-0.8) { folder open };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This solution was cribbed from other sources (`dogeared` shape was taken from the [GitDAGs](https://github.com/Jubobs/gitdags) project with some changes, and handling of parameters was based on code in [guidatikzmark](https://github.com/GuITeX/guidatikzmark) project (Italian TUG: [GuIT](http://www.guitex.org)). It is by no means complete solution, in particular handling connecting nodes doesn't work completely correctly.

As you can see there isn't any correction for the text box...

The result looks like this:

[image: 'dogeared' and 'folder open' node shapes in PGF/TikZ]

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Folder_open_alt_font_awesome.svg) and download the `Folder_open_alt_font_awesome.svg`. There are [more icons in the same directory](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Font_Awesome_4_icons).
2. `convert Folder_open_alt_font_awesome.svg FolderOpen.pdf`
3. Use the PDF

As egreg explained:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\FolderOpen}[1][.8\ht\strutbox]{%
  \includegraphics[height=#1]{FolderOpen}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\FolderOpen] This is an open folder
\item This isn't
\end{itemize}

Also a big open folder: \FolderOpen[1cm].
\end{document}
```