# How do I create layers when drawing a symbol for a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

How do I draw the same picture as a node in figure 1 as with just tikz (to the left)?

[image]

This is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{ remember picture,
SYMBOL/.style = {rectangle,
%line width=1pt,
draw,
semithick,
align=center,
label={below:#1},
label={center:\usebox\symbolI},
minimum size=0.5cm
},
}

\newsavebox\symbolI
\savebox\symbolI{%
\tikz\filldraw[line width=0.7pt, fill=cyan, fill opacity=1] (0,-0.1)ellipse (0.2cm and 0.1cm);
\tikz\filldraw[line width=0.7pt, fill=cyan, fill opacity=1] (0,0)ellipse (0.2cm and 0.1cm);%
\tikz\filldraw[line width=0.7pt, fill=cyan, fill opacity=1] (0,0.1)ellipse (0.2cm and 0.1cm);%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw[line width=0.7pt, fill=cyan, fill opacity=1] (0,-0.1)ellipse (0.2cm and 0.1cm);
                 \filldraw[line width=0.7pt, fill=cyan, fill opacity=1] (0,0)ellipse (0.2cm and 0.1cm);%
                         \filldraw[line width=0.7pt, fill=cyan, fill opacity=1] (0,0.1)ellipse (0.2cm and 0.1cm);%
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[SYMBOL] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Signs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do the 3 ellipses have to be placed in a box whose edges are traced?

Comment: I did not understand your question but I edited the post with what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using the labels that are used to add a node around the main node, just use the `node contents` key to fill the node by leaving the braces empty: `\node[SYMBOL] {};`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{SYMBOL/.style = {%
%line width=1pt,% <-- useless with semithick
draw,
semithick,
inner sep=4pt,% <-- invisible separation space of 4pt inside the shape
node contents={\usebox\symbolI},%<-- sets the contents of the node
%minimum size=0.5cm %<-- useless
}
}

\newsavebox\symbolI
\savebox\symbolI{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\filldraw[line width=0.7pt, fill=cyan, fill opacity=1] (0,-0.1)ellipse (0.2cm and 0.1cm);%
\filldraw[line width=0.7pt, fill=cyan, fill opacity=1] (0,0)ellipse (0.2cm and 0.1cm);%
\filldraw[line width=0.7pt, fill=cyan, fill opacity=1] (0,0.1)ellipse (0.2cm and 0.1cm);%
%    \path[] (current bounding box.north east)rectangle(current bounding box.south west);%<- uncomment to see the inside box
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[SYMBOL] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Signs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

A figure like this can be drawn with a `double copy shadow` from `shadows` library and the external border with the `show background rectangle` from `backgrounds` library.

But the bounding box is not always correct when `shadows` library is used, therefore another alternative could be to repeat the path with a `preaction` and `postaction` options. Now the bounding box is correct and one command is enough to draw the whole figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mystyle/.style={line width=.7pt, fill=cyan, draw, fill opacity=1},
    show background rectangle]
\filldraw[mystyle, 
    postaction={mystyle, transform canvas={yshift=0.1cm}}, preaction={mystyle, transform canvas={yshift=-0.1cm}}] (0,0) ellipse (0.2cm and 0.1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Signs}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For the compare purpose with [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/).

```
// name.asy
// output: name.pdf
unitsize(1cm);
transform t=shift(0,0.1);
filldraw(ellipse((0,0),0.2,0.1),blue);
filldraw(t*ellipse((0,0),0.2,0.1),blue);
filldraw(t^2*ellipse((0,0),0.2,0.1),blue);
shipout(bbox(1mm,FillDraw(white,black)));
```

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\SYMBOL}[1][.8\ht\strutbox]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174662/213378
    \includegraphics[height=#1]{name.pdf}%
}
\begin{document}
    Hello World!    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
\includegraphics{name.pdf}
\caption{Signs}
    \end{figure}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\SYMBOL] This is an open folder
    \item This isn't
\end{itemize}
Also a big open folder: \SYMBOL[1cm].
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This way is plain.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum} % >>> for dummy texts
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {-1,0,1}
\draw[fill=cyan,thick,shift={(0,\i*.1)}] (0,0) circle(.2 and .1);
\draw (45:.5) rectangle (-135:.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Signs}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```