# Symbol for eye (looking for a library)

Tags: graphics, symbols

I was wondering if anybody knows about Latex symbol for an eye, either frontal or lateral view.

Frontal:

[image]

Lateral:

[image]

*Update* I knew about Detexify and searched there. It didn't work. Detexify took the eyes as some malformed alphabetic characters.

Comment: The [comprehensive symbol list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) is the place to look for this type of request. Searching that document for 'eye' will find the `fontawesome` symbol `\faEye` as well as the `dingbat` symbol `\eye`.

Comment: @SandyG Good information. Thanks!

Comment: There is Unicode U+1F441

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have created two eyes symbols with [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor)➡TikZ that reproduce largely your picture that they can be used in text and in math mode. Your names are `\frontaleye` and `\lateraleye`. With `\scalebox{<factor>}` you can increase or decrease the size of the symbols.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphics}
    \newcommand*\frontaleye{%
       \scalebox{0.25}{
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (84.83,179.7) .. controls (84.92,169.21) and (100.66,160.85) .. (119.99,161.01) .. controls (139.32,161.18) and (154.92,169.81) .. (154.83,180.3) .. controls (152.72,170.91) and (137.95,163.54) .. (119.97,163.39) .. controls (101.99,163.23) and (87.1,170.35) .. (84.83,179.7) -- cycle ;
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (102.39,180.93) .. controls (102.39,171.24) and (110.25,163.39) .. (119.93,163.39) .. controls (129.62,163.39) and (137.47,171.24) .. (137.47,180.93) .. controls (137.47,190.61) and (129.62,198.47) .. (119.93,198.47) .. controls (110.25,198.47) and (102.39,190.61) .. (102.39,180.93) -- cycle ;
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (107,174) .. controls (107,171.24) and (109.24,169) .. (112,169) .. controls (114.76,169) and (117,171.24) .. (117,174) .. controls (117,176.76) and (114.76,179) .. (112,179) .. controls (109.24,179) and (107,176.76) .. (107,174) -- cycle ;
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (154.65,179.7) .. controls (154.65,190.58) and (139.02,199.41) .. (119.74,199.41) .. controls (100.46,199.41) and (84.83,190.58) .. (84.83,179.7) .. controls (85.71,190.15) and (101,198.47) .. (119.74,198.47) .. controls (138.48,198.47) and (153.77,190.15) .. (154.65,179.7) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}}
\,}
    
    \newcommand*\lateraleye{%
       \scalebox{0.15}{
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
    \draw  [line width=1.5]  (300,100.33) .. controls (326,122) and (352,135) .. (378,139.33) .. controls (352,143.67) and (326,156.67) .. (300,178.33) ;
    \draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (308.94,116.33) .. controls (313.87,116.33) and (317.86,125.51) .. (317.85,136.83) .. controls (317.84,148.15) and (313.84,157.33) .. (308.91,157.33) .. controls (303.99,157.32) and (300,148.14) .. (300.01,136.82) .. controls (300.02,125.5) and (304.02,116.32) .. (308.94,116.33) -- cycle ;
    \draw  [draw opacity=0][line width=1.5]  (314.84,166.6) .. controls (311.87,164.64) and (309.14,162.18) .. (306.76,159.24) .. controls (295.12,144.82) and (296.6,124.33) .. (310.07,113.45) .. controls (311.48,112.32) and (312.96,111.33) .. (314.5,110.49) -- (331.14,139.55) -- cycle ; \draw  [line width=1.5]  (314.84,166.6) .. controls (311.87,164.64) and (309.14,162.18) .. (306.76,159.24) .. controls (295.12,144.82) and (296.6,124.33) .. (310.07,113.45) .. controls (311.48,112.32) and (312.96,111.33) .. (314.5,110.49) ;
    \draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (304.43,124.2) .. controls (306.09,124.25) and (307.32,128.01) .. (307.18,132.6) .. controls (307.05,137.19) and (305.59,140.88) .. (303.93,140.83) .. controls (302.27,140.78) and (301.03,137.02) .. (301.17,132.43) .. controls (301.31,127.83) and (302.76,124.15) .. (304.43,124.2) -- cycle ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }\,}
    
    \begin{document}
    This is a \frontaleye frontal eye in text mode. In math-mode you have:
    \[d\colon \frontaleye \to \mathbb{N}\]
    
    Let \lateraleye text lateral eye in text mode and in math-mode:
    \[r\colon \lateraleye \to \mathbb{Z}\]
    \end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that it is possibile to choose the color of the eye.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphics}
    \newcommand*\frontaleye{%
       \scalebox{0.25}{
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 140; green, 196; blue, 74 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (104.5,179.99) .. controls (104.5,171.39) and (111.48,164.41) .. (120.08,164.41) .. controls (128.68,164.41) and (135.66,171.39) .. (135.66,179.99) .. controls (135.66,188.6) and (128.68,195.57) .. (120.08,195.57) .. controls (111.48,195.57) and (104.5,188.6) .. (104.5,179.99) -- cycle ;
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (84.83,179.7) .. controls (84.92,169.21) and (100.66,160.85) .. (119.99,161.01) .. controls (139.32,161.18) and (154.92,169.81) .. (154.83,180.3) .. controls (152.49,171.04) and (137.8,163.81) .. (119.97,163.66) .. controls (102.13,163.51) and (87.32,170.48) .. (84.83,179.7) -- cycle ;
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (113.6,179.91) .. controls (113.6,176.19) and (116.63,173.16) .. (120.36,173.16) .. controls (124.08,173.16) and (127.11,176.19) .. (127.11,179.91) .. controls (127.11,183.64) and (124.08,186.67) .. (120.36,186.67) .. controls (116.63,186.67) and (113.6,183.64) .. (113.6,179.91) -- cycle ;
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (195,141) .. controls (195,138.24) and (197.24,136) .. (200,136) .. controls (202.76,136) and (205,138.24) .. (205,141) .. controls (205,143.76) and (202.76,146) .. (200,146) .. controls (197.24,146) and (195,143.76) .. (195,141) -- cycle ;
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (154.65,179.7) .. controls (154.65,190.58) and (139.02,199.41) .. (119.74,199.41) .. controls (100.46,199.41) and (84.83,190.58) .. (84.83,179.7) .. controls (87.23,189.3) and (101.95,196.67) .. (119.74,196.67) .. controls (137.53,196.67) and (152.25,189.3) .. (154.65,179.7) -- cycle ;
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (125.45,172.24) .. controls (125.45,170.4) and (126.94,168.91) .. (128.78,168.91) .. controls (130.62,168.91) and (132.11,170.4) .. (132.11,172.24) .. controls (132.11,174.08) and (130.62,175.57) .. (128.78,175.57) .. controls (126.94,175.57) and (125.45,174.08) .. (125.45,172.24) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}\kern-.5em}
    
    \begin{document}
    This is a \frontaleye frontal colored eye in text mode and in math-mode
    \[d\colon \frontaleye \to \mathbb{N}\]
    
  
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The green eye looks cool!

Comment: @xxx--- LOL :-)))) You are free to change the color of the eye.

Answer (score 11):

After checking user [TrongVuong1998](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213378/user213378)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/562240/38244), I went to the [linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174662/213378) out of curiosity. And I discovered [`fontAwesome`](https://fontawesome.com/). So, here's my two cents to my own question:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{24}{0}\selectfont
\faEye
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you use the [dingbat](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/dingbat/dingbat.pdf) package, you will get a frontal view of an eye by typing `\eye`.

Answer (score 2):

Also `pst-optic` package have your original `\eye` as shown in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-optic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*\latseye{%
       \scalebox{0.25}{\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
\rput(1,-.5){\eye}
\end{pspicture}\kern1em}}
\newcommand*\latdeye{%
       \reflectbox{\scalebox{0.25}{\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
\rput(1,-.5){\eye}
\end{pspicture}\kern.2em}}}

\begin{document}
\latseye and \latdeye
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another eye is that of `protosem` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{protosem}
\begin{document}
\textproto{\Aayin}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're a genius!

Comment: @xxx--- Definitely not a lamp genius :-))). I am a humble person like many others in this world and I want to stay that way.